# How to reduce the size of image files

Tags: android

I have just exported my wallpapers app using eclipse, and it has around 77 SD - HD wallpapers. However, whilst most apps with this many images are around 3.1MB in size, my app is over 10x that size, at 32MB. Is there any way I can go about reducing the size of the images in my app? And I don't mean decodeStream and all that business, I mean reducing an image from being 320kB to 200/100kB, and reducing the size oof the APK as a result. I've looked online, but have found nothing.

I hope that this post will help others in my situation in the future, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: Helpful link: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: if you compress those images to reduce apk size, it certainly lose density, can you place those images into http server, then download whenever necessary?

Comment: Vince, that sounds like a great idea :) Do you know of any good tutorials online for how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create new image bitmap for old image, and you need to resize your image pixel so that you can get small size image
This code can get resize bitmap so that you can convert bitmap to image

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromFile(File dst) {
    if (null != dst && dst.exists()) {
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = null;
        opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dst.getPath(), opts);
        // calculate image size
        int width;
        int height;
        if (opts.outHeight > opts.outWidth) {
            height = 80;
            width = 50;
        }
        else {
            height = 60;
            width = 80;
        }

        final int minSideLength = Math.min(width, height);
        opts.inSampleSize = computeSampleSize(opts, minSideLength,
                width * height);
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        opts.inInputShareable = true;
        opts.inPurgeable = true;

        try {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dst.getPath(), opts);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static int computeSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int minSideLength, int maxNumOfPixels) {
    int initialSize = computeInitialSampleSize(options, minSideLength,
            maxNumOfPixels);

    int roundedSize;
    if (initialSize <= 8) {
        roundedSize = 1;
        while (roundedSize < initialSize) {
            roundedSize <<= 1;
        }
    } else {
        roundedSize = (initialSize + 7) / 8 * 8;
    } 
    return roundedSize;
}

private static int computeInitialSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int minSideLength, int maxNumOfPixels) {
    double w = options.outWidth;
    double h = options.outHeight;

    int lowerBound = (maxNumOfPixels == -1) ? 1 :
            (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(w * h / maxNumOfPixels));
    int upperBound = (minSideLength == -1) ? 128 :
            (int) Math.min(Math.floor(w / minSideLength),
            Math.floor(h / minSideLength));

    if (upperBound < lowerBound) {
        return lowerBound;
    }

    if ((maxNumOfPixels == -1) &&
            (minSideLength == -1)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (minSideLength == -1) {
        return lowerBound;
    } else {
        return upperBound;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573774/how-to-reduce-an-image-file-size-before-uploading-to-a-server)

```
private String decodeFile(String path,int DESIREDWIDTH, int DESIREDHEIGHT) {
    String strMyImagePath = null;
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    try {
        // Part 1: Decode image
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.decodeFile(path, DESIREDWIDTH, DESIREDHEIGHT, ScalingLogic.FIT);

        if (!(unscaledBitmap.getWidth() <= DESIREDWIDTH && unscaledBitmap.getHeight() <= DESIREDHEIGHT)) {
            // Part 2: Scale image
            scaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, DESIREDWIDTH, DESIREDHEIGHT, ScalingLogic.FIT);
        } else {
            unscaledBitmap.recycle();
            return path;
        }

        // Store to tmp file

        String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File mFolder = new File(extr + "/TMMFOLDER");
        if (!mFolder.exists()) {
            mFolder.mkdir();
        }

        String s = "tmp.png";

        File f = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), s);

        strMyImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        scaledBitmap.recycle();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }

    if (strMyImagePath == null) {
        return path;
    }
    return strMyImagePath;

}
```

**ScalingUtilities.java**

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;

/**
 * Class containing static utility methods for bitmap decoding and scaling
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class ScalingUtilities {

    /**
     * Utility function for decoding an image resource. The decoded bitmap will
     * be optimized for further scaling to the requested destination dimensions
     * and scaling logic.
     *
     * @param res The resources object containing the image data
     * @param resId The resource id of the image data
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Decoded bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeResource(Resources res, int resId, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        return unscaledBitmap;
    }
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(String path, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        return unscaledBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Utility function for creating a scaled version of an existing bitmap
     *
     * @param unscaledBitmap Bitmap to scale
     * @param dstWidth Wanted width of destination bitmap
     * @param dstHeight Wanted height of destination bitmap
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return New scaled bitmap object
     */
    public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap unscaledBitmap, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Rect srcRect = calculateSrcRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Rect dstRect = calculateDstRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(unscaledBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        return scaledBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * ScalingLogic defines how scaling should be carried out if source and
     * destination image has different aspect ratio.
     *
     * CROP: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure that at least
     * one of the two dimensions fit inside the requested destination area.
     * Parts of the source image will be cropped to realize this.
     *
     * FIT: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure both
     * dimensions fit inside the requested destination area. The resulting
     * destination dimensions might be adjusted to a smaller size than
     * requested.
     */
    public static enum ScalingLogic {
        CROP, FIT
    }

    /**
     * Calculate optimal down-sampling factor given the dimensions of a source
     * image, the dimensions of a destination area and a scaling logic.
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal down scaling sample size for decoding
     */
    public static int calculateSampleSize(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            } else {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            }
        } else {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            } else {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates source rectangle for scaling bitmap
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal source rectangle
     */
    public static Rect calculateSrcRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.CROP) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                final int srcRectWidth = (int)(srcHeight * dstAspect);
                final int srcRectLeft = (srcWidth - srcRectWidth) / 2;
                return new Rect(srcRectLeft, 0, srcRectLeft + srcRectWidth, srcHeight);
            } else {
                final int srcRectHeight = (int)(srcWidth / dstAspect);
                final int scrRectTop = (int)(srcHeight - srcRectHeight) / 2;
                return new Rect(0, scrRectTop, srcWidth, scrRectTop + srcRectHeight);
            }
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates destination rectangle for scaling bitmap
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal destination rectangle
     */
    public static Rect calculateDstRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, (int)(dstWidth / srcAspect));
            } else {
                return new Rect(0, 0, (int)(dstHeight * srcAspect), dstHeight);
            }
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
        }
    }

}
```

Using Bitmap.compress() you just specify compression algorithm and by the way compression operation takes rather big amount of time. If you need to play with sizes for reducing memory allocation for your image, you exactly need to use scaling of your image using Bitmap.Options, computing bitmap bounds at first and then decoding it to your specified size.

You can [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response :) Will this reduce my images from being 300kB to, say, 100kB (kilobytes), though? That was the original question - It seems like the above is for resizing images in the app :P