# upload image from imageview to firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, imageview, firebase-storage

i have an activity with some images in a recycler view. I want to upload them into firebase storage as profile pictures but i don't know how. 
I have an activity with 2 image view: the first upload images from phone gallery the second one open this activity below. My idea is: click one image, it uploads the image clicked to firebase and when is finished return to last activity because user need to choose a nickname too.

```
package it.evilsecret.evilsecretappfinal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ImageSelection extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CHOOSE_IMAGE = 101;
ImageView imageView;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
List<Image> imageList;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imageselectionpopup);

    imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));

    imageList.add(
            new Image(R.drawable.alis, "Alis"));
    imageList.add(
            new Image(R.drawable.astaroth, "Astaroth"));
    imageList.add(
            new Image(R.drawable.chris, "Chris"));
    imageList.add(
            new Image(R.drawable.sarah, "Sarah"));
    imageList.add(
            new Image(R.drawable.vanessa, "Vanessa"));

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save bitmap to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885860/how-to-save-bitmap-to-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to convert the image to bitmap [(convert image to bitmap)](https://www.android-examples.com/convert-drawable-image-into-bitmap-in-android/)and then compress it. After that you have to upload it to firebase cloud [link to firebase cloud](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

Answer (score 0):

Convert to Bitmap first...

```
Bitmap bitImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageList.get(0));
```

Then compress it to reduce its size...

```
bitImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
```

Refer this link..
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-tutorial-android/