# How to retrieve and store user profile picture from photo uri provided by Firebase in android (kotlin)?

Tags: android, image, firebase, kotlin, bitmap

This is possibly a duplicate question but none of the codes helped me and some answers are old and now deprecated. I'm making an android application and in that I want to retrieve and store the user's profile picture in my app. The uri of the image is provided by FirebaseUser class as uri  but I want to know how to retrieve bitmap from the uri and save it in apps 'filesDir()' folder and get a drawable image from it whenever I want it. I have obviously tried some codes but none of it is working.
Two ways I have tried :-

```
fun getBitmap(context: Context, selectedImage: Uri): Bitmap? {
  val imageStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(selectedImage)
  val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, BitmapFactory.Options())
  imageStream?.close()
  return image
}
```

Another method I found was using ImageDecoder and MediaStore's `getBitmap()` *(which is deprecated)*

```
 val bitmap = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, Uri.parse("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/link"))) //here parsing a google account profile pic link
             } else {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, Uri.parse("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/link"))
             }
```

The problem is whenever I  try any of it the app just keeps crashing with exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider`.
Am I missing something? Do we need any manifest configuration in app to access uri from internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use Glide, here is the documentation: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Glide is a library where by just calling their method and passing the URL you need you are going to be good.

---

I will explain to you how to prepare it,

Download it using Gradle,

```
 repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   google()
 }

 dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
   annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
 }
```

Then Use it :)

```
imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
Glide.with(this).load("http://yoururl.png").into(imageView)
```

This is to Save the Image into Firebase: [How to save bitmap to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885860/how-to-save-bitmap-to-firebase)

I recommend your app works with Firebase database and you save your image URL'S into your user profile in the database

best,
and do magic :)