# How to Reduce the image Quality or Resolution before it uploaded to the Storage to save Storage place?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview

Hello every one iam working on a social app which on of its features is uploading images

i Use Firebase in this project
but for a starter project i use Free plan for which gives me 5GB storage free

So   i want to know how to Reduce the image Quality  or Resolution  before it uploaded to the Storage  to save Storage place

here is my code

> UploadpostActivity

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode ==RESULT_OK ){

        mImageURI = data.getData();
        imgSelector.setImageURI(mImageURI);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    btnUpload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
    imgSelector =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectImage);
    postDescription = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.descpost);
    postTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.titlepost);
    mProgress= new ProgressDialog(this);


    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            postnow();
        }
    });
    imgSelector.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent gallerySelectIntent = new 
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            gallerySelectIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(gallerySelectIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);

        }
    });



 }

private void postnow(){


    mProgress.setMessage("Uploading..");
    mProgress.show();


    String title= postTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    String desc = postDescription.getText().toString().trim();


   StorageReference pathfile = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
           .getReference("UsersImages")
           .child(mImageURI.getLastPathSegment());


    pathfile.putFile(mImageURI)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new 
    OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) 
    {
                    // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"Upload 
          Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    // ...

                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"Something Went Wrong 
       , Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

  }
  }
```

I Appreciate your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce an Image file size before uploading to a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573774/how-to-reduce-an-image-file-size-before-uploading-to-a-server)

Answer (score 1):

decrease size of bitmap by this method and upload it to server..

```
public static Bitmap resizeBitmapKeepAspectRatio(Bitmap originalImage, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        float originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
        float originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);

        float scale = width / originalWidth;

        float xTranslation = 0.0f;
        float yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale) / 2.0f;

        Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
        transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
        transformation.preScale(scale, scale);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, transformation, paint);

        return cropBitmapTransparency(background);
    }


public static Bitmap cropBitmapTransparency(Bitmap sourceBitmap) {
        int minX = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
        int minY = sourceBitmap.getHeight();
        int maxX = -1;
        int maxY = -1;
        for (int y = 0; y < sourceBitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < sourceBitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
                int alpha = (sourceBitmap.getPixel(x, y) >> 24) & 255;
                if (alpha > 0)   // pixel is not 100% transparent
                {
                    if (x < minX)
                        minX = x;
                    if (x > maxX)
                        maxX = x;
                    if (y < minY)
                        minY = y;
                    if (y > maxY)
                        maxY = y;
                }
            }
        }
        if ((maxX < minX) || (maxY < minY))
            return null; // Bitmap is entirely transparent

        // crop bitmap to non-transparent area and return:
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, minX, minY, (maxX - minX) + 1, (maxY - minY) + 1);
    }
```

Comment: is there any way to resize it with Picasso or Glide Library

Comment: This answer solves your issue and you just need to pass the arguments.  Why do you need any third party libraries to do the same??

Comment: currently glide or picasso doesn't support to resize image while uploading or fetching it from server, you have resize your bitmap manually and pass it to glide or picasso.