# Resizing an Image?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a big size image programmatically , but app is crashing.
Here is what I'm doing:

```
public static Bitmap getImageFromResult(Context context, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    File imageFile = getTempFile(context);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage;
        boolean isCamera = (imageReturnedIntent == null || imageReturnedIntent.getData() == null || imageReturnedIntent.getData().toString().contains(imageFile.toString()));

        if (isCamera) {
            // From Camera
            selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        } else {
            // From Storage
            selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        }

        //bitmap = getResizedImage(context, selectedImage);
        bitmap = getResizedImage(context, selectedImage);

    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

And the `resize`method` :

```
//*********** Resize to avoid using too much Memory loading Big Images (2560*1920) ********//

private static Bitmap getResizedImage(Context context, Uri selectedImage) {
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = null;
    int[] sampleSizes = new int[]{8,7,6,5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    int i = 0;
    do {
        resizedBitmap = decodeBitmap(context, selectedImage, sampleSizes[i]);
        i++;

    } while (resizedBitmap.getWidth() < minWidthQuality && i < sampleSizes.length);

    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: show your log cat (error log)

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do here.  If you need to use a bitmap in your Android app, most likely you don't need to store very large versions of it, even for xxhdpi.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - you can resize the Bitmap to another height/width

```
 public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, float newHeight, float newWidth) {
        float width = bm.getWidth();
        float height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = (newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = (newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, (int) width, (int) height, matrix, false);
    }
```

Then just make your new Bitmap

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathname);
 Bitmap newBitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap,400,320);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting image live from internet then obviously you need to first download the image but it will take time according to internet speed  or you want to load image from memory  then you can apply this  [stack over answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18574118/8040930)
method here to get decrease the image quality