# Android image size reduction

Tags: android, image

I got an app which is loaded with many image files which takes much place. The app can also download more pictures from different sources. Is there a way to compress their size?

I remember there was maybe some sort of library created by Google specifically for this issue?

Comment: Images are online or displaying from drawable only.

Comment: You can use `Compressor` library: https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor

Comment: Reduce an Image file size before uploading to a server
Try this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18574118/9318537)