# Android: Compress Bitmap from Uri

Tags: android

Take a picture with the normal smartphone camera.

Ok I've been Googling this for a while now, and everyone seems to use something like the following:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri));
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, out);
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
```

I use this to check the file size:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
protected int sizeOf(Bitmap data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
        return data.getRowBytes() * data.getHeight();
    } else {
        return data.getByteCount();
    }
}
```

The Bitmap is not getting any smaller, before and after:

```
Log.d("image", sizeOf(bm)+"");
Log.d("image", sizeOf(decoded)+"");
```

Results:

```
11-05 02:51:52.739: D/image(2558): 20155392
11-05 02:51:52.739: D/image(2558): 20155392
```

Pointers?

**Answer:**

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 50;
Bitmap bmpSample = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);

Log.d("image", sizeOf(bmpPic)+"");

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                
bmSample.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 1, out);
byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();

Log.d("image", byteArray.length/1024+"");
```

Comment: Where do you put your log statements..?

Comment: Directly after I invoke sizeOf(Bitmap data)!

Comment: Can you post it in code? I have the feeling that you may be logging size of same data.. hence output is same..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I thought so aswell, I double checked though, I know the output is on the same second (weird :S).

Comment: See my answer.. explains why the output is same.. if you are trying to display a compressed version on the screen you should be using `inSampleSize` .. read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11061315/827110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compress` method, as mentioned in the documentation:

> Write a compressed version of the bitmap to the specified outputstream. The bitmap can be reconstructed by passing a corresponding inputstream to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`

Thus the variable `out` now contains the compressed bitmap. Since you check the size after calling `decodeStream` the bitmap is **decompressed** and returned to you. Therefore the size is same.