# Lower uri image quality to reduce file size

Tags: java, android, uri

I have a high resolution `image` `Uri` and I would like to reduce the image quality and size since i'm uploading it to a server and then load it afterwards as a smaller version of the original image.

I tried this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(image).resize(100,100).get();
```

But it didn't work cause you need to do this from a separate `Thread` and I didn't find a listener that tells you when the resizing is over.

Does anyone has a solution that can **reduce the image quality to get a smaller file size?**

Answer (score 2):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 50;
Bitmap bmpSample = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                
bmpSample.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 1, out);
byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();
return convertToUri(byteArray);
```

Thank you [Android: Compress Bitmap from Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19780812/4369107)

Comment: How do you convert byteArray to Uri in convertToUri?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in your `Uri`.

Step #2: Create a `BitmapFactory.Options` object, with an `inSampleSize` to control the degree of downsampling that you want to do, to create a lower-resolution `Bitmap`.

Step #3: Pass the stream and the `BitmapFactory.Options` object to `decodeStream()` on `BitmapFactory`, to get a downsampled `Bitmap`.

Step #4: Upload that `Bitmap`, where the details will vary a bit by whatever API you are using to do the upload (`byte[]`, `File`, etc.).

Step #5: Do steps #1-4 on a background thread, as you should not be doing disk I/O, bitmap downsampling, and network operations on the main application thread.